# mismatch most recent responses and number of answsers on a question

Tags: support, specific-question

According to the most recent responses I have 3 answers to a question. But when I go to the actual question there are only 2.

On the most recent responses I can see the first 2 lines of an answer from Marc Gravell, it would be very nice to see the rest. Feels like watching a film on VHS, where they say "the killer is " and then you run out of tape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rascal Marc [deleted his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334366/hierarchy-of-transactionscope/1334412#1334412), and [as devinb notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17725/mismatch-most-recent-responses-and-number-of-answsers-on-a-question/17727#17727), this'll kinda screw with the recent activity. Don't worry about it - most likely, Marc felt the existing answers better answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

If a user adds an answer and then deletes it, it will appear in your "recent events" but will not appear on your question anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Dupe: See this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7598/superuser-homepage-answer-bug).

Comment: Add a comment to the question next time.

Comment: Why?  There is no concensus on whether dupe links should be comments or answers (as has been discussed before).  I think answers are where they should be put, since that will bring more peoples attention to the dupe.